# How to record call in Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I want to record the calling using `android` `marshmallow` for that i have used the below code

```
 myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                //myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
                myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
                myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
```

but i am getting below on my logcat

```
    Request requires android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT
 E/AudioPolicyIntefaceImpl: getInputForAttr() permission denied: capture not allowed
```

Any idea how to record call on marshmallow

Answer (score 0):

This permission is not allowed for third party apps. Check this link.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT

Comment: Is it not even allowed if I have root, and if I move the app to be a system app?

Answer (score -1):

You need to ask for permission at runtime

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT},
                    1);
```

And do processing later in

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
 switch (requestCode) {
    case 1: {
     for(int i:grantResults){
       if(i == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
         // do your stuff here.
        }
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: Yes I have done this this but its not recording the call  E/AudioPolicyIntefaceImpl: getInputForAttr() permission denied: capture not allowed have you done call recording???

Comment: I am also working on Call recording but unable to record call.I am working on this from 5 days please help me on this